# Multiple matches of regex within other regex

Tags: regex

Lets say I have the following string:
"blablaoneblablablaone",
and I want to match the "bla" matches within "one...one",
Which means that the first two "bla"s wont be captured as they come before "one".

Its easy to accomplish using regex twice (one to match everything between "one...one" and one to match "bla"s), but my question is about whether it is possible to accomplish using a single regex.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use look-around.

```
(?<=one)(bla)*(?=one)
```

Positive look-behind (`(?<=...)`) checks that the previous characters match some pattern.

Positive look-ahead (`(?=...)`) checks that the next characters match some pattern.

Look-around is not included in the matched string.

[Test](http://www.rubular.com/r/SHapJXfGpO).

Or you can simply put the part you want to extract in brackets and extract group 1. (the `?:` is to make (bla) a non-capturing group, it doesn't change the match, just what gets captured).

```
one((?:bla)*)one
```

[Test](http://www.rubular.com/r/P8n9uEgMUC).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex: `/(?:one)([bla]+)(?:one)/g`. It can be tested here: http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex

Comment: This matches `onebbbbbbone` as well, since `[bla]` means a `b`, an `l` or an `a`, not the sequence `bla`.

Comment: Correct. This way it will match exactly **bla**: `/(?:one)((?:bla)+)(?:one)/g`. **?:** means non-capturing group, so it will be a matched text, but not in the $1. It can be tested here: http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex